# Autolayout of multi UIlables in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I'd like to implement a layout of a `UITableViewCell` in iOS8 which looks like:
[image]

The point is each label can be ***multi-lines***. I know it needs a correct configuration of hugging/compress, but I don't know how to set it.
I set the constraints following:

1. set the each `numberOfLine` to 0
2. set `leftLabel1` constraints: top to superview, leading to superview, width
3. set `rightLabel1` constraints: leading to leftLabel1, trailing to superview,bottom Edges with leftLabel1
4. set `leftLabel2` constraints: top to leftLabel1's bottom, align leading && trailing edges of leftLabel1
5. set `rightLabel2` constraints: leading to leftLabel2, trailing to superview, bottom edge with leftLabel2
6. set `leftLabel3` constraints: top to leftLabel2's bottom, align leading && trailing edges of leftLabel1
7. set `rightLabel3` constraints: leading to leftLabel3, trailing to superview, bottom edge with leftLabel3

Then it's time to set hugging and compression resistance, but I failed to add it and not all the labels can show the text correctly.
Could anyone make a detail explanation for how to implement it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you get each label height dynamically from this method

```
-(CGFloat)heightForCellText:(NSString *)text withWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,width,CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    lbl.lineBreakMode =NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0];
    lbl.text = text;
    [lbl sizeToFit];
    return lbl.frame.size.height;
}
```

and set the table cell height like this

```
 return [self heightForCellText:leftLabel withWidth:leftLabel.size.width] + Defult_Cell_Height;
```

Comment: I Know but cell size is not change according to content height